# Find all entire functions that satisfy following inequality $|f(z)|\leq|\cos(z)|$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Find all entire functions $f(z)$ that satisfy
$$|f(z)|\leq|\cos(z)|$$
for all $z\in \mathbb{C}.$

So the first thing that has crossed my mind is to apply Liouville´s Theorem, which would imply that our function has to be constant but I am struggling with calculating anything from this point on. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: $\text{cos}(z)$ is not a bounded function on the complex plane.

Comment: You can apply it to the meromorphic function $g(z)=f(z)/\cos(z)$, which is bounded by $1$. The singularities at the zeros of $\cos(z)$ will be removable, for $g(z)$ being bounded.

Comment: @Laci oh thank you, I have totally forgotten that fact.

Comment: @user8667 thank you! So just to sum up to be sure if I have understood correctly. If we define $g(z)$ as you mentioned and we know that it is bounded by 1, singularities are removable due to Riemman´s rem. sing. theoremthen we can apply Liouville´s, and say it that $f(z)=M* \cos(z)$ where $|M|\leq 1$

Comment: Yes, that's all.

Comment: @user85667 if you wanna copy your comments as an answer I will accept it. :)

Comment: @user85667 Clever idea! I did not think of it.